# Хитрая маршрутизация

Tags: сеть

Доброго времени суток.

Ситуация следующая: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подсетка 192.168.0.1/24 прописана в таблицах маршрутизации 192.168.10.1/24 и соответственно пакеты проходят как туда так и оттуда корректно.  Сеть 192.168.1.0/24 в сетке 192.168.10.0/24 не прописана, соответственно пакеты не получают обратного ответа. На машинее 192.168.10.1 прописана еще одно сетка с обратной связью в таблице 192.168.4.0/24.
Хочется - диапазон адресов 102.168.1.10-30 пускать через NAT связанный с виртуальным интерфейсом на этой же машине (где расположены eth1,eth0,eth2), с адресом скажем 192.168.4.1 - с этого интерфейса пакеты должны корректно после NAT на нем проходить к машине 192.168.10.1. Это гипотетически позволит получить корректную связь между срезом хостов из недоступной напрямую сетке 192.168.1.0/24 по отношению к машине на той стороне тунеля  - 192.168.10.1.

Гуру маршрутизации - подскажите как лучше реализовать описанную схему. И будет ли она вообще работать. Машина-шлюз отдельный сервер на котором физически расположены 3 интерфейса и тунель. Ofc **ip_forward=TRUE**.

***Решение: 
пошел простым "тупым" способом,***

**iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.1 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.1**

результат:

```
(свитч "сидящий" на VoIP трафике)
FEPoEL2-SW26(diag)# ping 192.168.21.26
Gateway      : 192.168.1.2
192.168.21.26 is alive.
```

дамп tcpdump

```
23:15:12.002799 IP 192.168.0.1 > 192.168.21.26: ICMP echo request, id 44295, 
seq 1536, length 30
23:15:12.010786 IP 192.168.21.26 > 192.168.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 44295, 
seq 1536, length 30
23:17:21.184955 IP 192.168.0.1 > 192.168.21.26: ICMP echo request, id 44295, 
seq 1792, length 30
23:17:21.192869 IP 192.168.21.26 > 192.168.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 44295, 
seq 1792, length 30
```

как видим подмена корректно работает, таблица хэшей не перегружается, т.к. диапазон "серых" за NAT'ом адресов очень мал.

Comment: если есть другие варианты решения этой задачи, попрошу написать свои варианты для общего просвещения